# Using @page Route Template breaks razor component in razor page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, razor-components

I have the following razor page Index.cshtml:

```
@page "/Test/{value?}"
@model Test01.Areas.Test.Pages.IndexModel


<h1>Test</h1>

<h3>@Model.value</h3>


@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Test01.Components.Test>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Test01.Areas.Test.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string value { get; set; } = "none";

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

With the razor component Test.razor:

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="openModal">Open Modal</button>
</div>


@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" @onclick="closeModal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Modal Body
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    Modal Footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<hr />

@code {
    protected bool showModal = false;

    protected void openModal()
    {
        this.showModal = true;
    }

    protected void closeModal()
    {
        this.showModal = false;
    }
}
```

When I call the page without a value such as:

https://localhost:44306/Test

It works as expected when I click the open modal button.

---

When I call the page with a value such as:

https://localhost:44306/Test/TestValue

Nothing happens when I click the open modal button.

---

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out shortly after.

I had to add:

```
<base href="~/" />
```

To the  tag of my _Layout.cshtml